# Identify a python thread over http (with django)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-views

On my django app I have a report (a csv download) that can take some time to run. When a user runs the report they are redirected to a 'processing' page where a javascript function checks the server every second to see if the csv has been created (the file name is included in the HttpResponse object).

What I'm looking for is a way of identifying the thread that's creating the csv. That way I can add an `estimated_time_to_completion` attribute to the thread, and include this info in the holding page. In fact I could stop checking for the existance of the (unlocked) csv - I could just ask the thread if it's finished.

My csv building thread looks something like -

```
class CsvBuilder(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, file_name, parameters)
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.parameters = parameters
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run():
        # ...
        file = open(self.file_name, 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for patient in patients:
            writer.writerow('some data')
            self.time_remaining = # a timedelta object
        file.close()
```

And then my django requests will look something like -

```
def create_csv(request):
    '''
    Standard django view to create a csv
    '''
    # get filename and parameters from request
    thread = CsvBuilder (file_name, parameters)
    return render_to_response('processing.html', {"thread_id": thread.thread_id})

def check_progress(request):
    '''
    An ajax call to check the progress on a report
    '''
    thread_id = requst.GET['thread_id']
    # find the thread 
    return HttpResponse(thread.time_remaining)
```

Is this possible? Or should I be going about this a different way?

Comment: Don't do this sort of thing with threads! Threads are not the right answer!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. At some level, there's got to be threading. Just sounds like I should be installing a third party app to handle it. That said, I'm still interested to know if what I'm suggesting is actually possible.. (and furthermore, why I shouldn't do it if it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you have your writer function update a memcached key/value for time_remaining calculations.

If it were me, I'd have probably used [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for the long running job, starting a thread from django seems like it could have pitfalls, but nothing specific is springing to mind.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easiest and safest to use dedicated background task library, they are designed for usecase like this. Most common for python is [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). It has good Django support and it's very easy to use.